# To prove the uniform convergence of a series of functions.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the series $\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{n(x+n)}$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$. If $f(x)$ be the sum of the series prove that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

I'm not able to find the sum function.
Abel test and dirichlet test don't work here.

How can I check the uniform convergence$?$

If it is uniform convergent then obviously $f$ should be continuous.

Comment: How is it obvious that $f$ should be continuous when the series converges uniformly?

Comment: Since each $f_{n}(x)$ in the sum function is continuous.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

Comment: @peter szilas. I forgot about M- weierstrass. Now I've solved it.Can you please tell if convergence of $\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{n(1+nx^{2})}$ can be checked using M- weierstrass. If no, then what test should I use for this one.$ (x \in R)$

Comment: Mathsaddict.Yes.Have a look at the Wiki link.$\dfrac{x}{n(n+x)}< 1/n^2=M_n$ (Weierstrass).Sum converges uniformly.Ok?

Comment: Mathaddict.$S_n(x)=\sum_{1}^n f_k(x)$ is continuos and converges uniformly to $f(x)$, then $f(x)$ is continuos.Done? All is well?

Comment: @Peter Szilas. Yes I've solved the problem that I have posted using M-weierstrass. Then what about $\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{n(1+nx^{2})}, x\in R?$

Comment: Mayhaddict. The partial sum S_n(x) are cont. and converging uniformly to f(x). This implies that f(x), the infinite sum, is continuos. Ok?

Comment: @peter szilas, ok.

Comment: Mayhaddict.Write it up nicely, showing every step.Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for first part: consider $ \frac{x}{n(x+n)} - \frac{x}{(n+m)(x+m+n)} $. If you rearrange it properly you will be left with 3 terms: $ \frac{1}{(m + n + x)} + \frac{(m + n - 1)}{(m + n)} - \frac{n}{(n + x)} $.

Try to recall the definition of Cauchy uniform convergence.

Fix $\epsilon$. Find $n$. You want the number above to be smaller than $\epsilon$ for all $m \geq n$ for all $x$.

Hint for continuity: Uniform Cauchy convergence implies continuity.

Comment: You need to consider the convergence of sequence of partial sums.